# Angular9 rxjs-behaviorsubject not working on different component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject, angular2-changedetection

I'm trying to udpate data in the real time from profile component to header component initially its working but after update any value from profile component  header observable not subscribe again. so I'm using a service with a BehaviorSubject and Subscription in the components like this.please check my code an what wrong my code:

**Service Code:**

```js
//Service (code related to the problem):
 this.userInfo = new BehaviorSubject(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')));
  this.updatedPageData = new BehaviorSubject('');
  this.userValue = this.userInfo.asObservable();
```

**Profile Component**

```js
   //updateData for emit updated value
   updateData(data){
      this.storage.saveDataInStorage(data);
      this.cmnFunction.userInfo.next(data);
   }
```

**Header Component**

```js
//Get values
 this.cmnFunction.userValue.subscribe(data=>{
    if(data != null) {
      this.currentUseInfo.name = data.name;
      this.currentUseInfo.image = data.image;
      this.currentUseInfo.role = data.role;
    }
  })
```

Can anybody tell me what the issue in my code?

Comment: Can you make a demo? It's very hard to tell what could be wrong. Are you sure you have just one instance of the service?

Comment: It looks like your subscription should receive the new value.  I'm with @martin on this one, are you sure you only have a single instance of the service?

Comment: @BizzyBob:yes sir i have create the single instance of a service i am not understand what the issue?

Comment: @martin:ok  i will create a demo for that and create single instance of a service

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior since you've re-assigned `userValue` with a another value, as shown in the following line: `this.userValue = this.userInfo.asObservable();`

Consider applying the following changes:

**Service Code:**

```js
private userInfoSource = new BehaviorSubject(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')));

public userValue = this.userInfoSource.asObservable();

public set updateUserInfo(value: string){
  this.userInfoSource.next(value)
}
```

**Profile Component**

```js
updateData(data){
  this.service.updateUserInfo = data
}
```

**Header Component**

```js
this.service.userValue.subscribe(data=>{
  if(data != null) {
    this.currentUseInfo.name = data.name;
    this.currentUseInfo.image = data.image;
    this.currentUseInfo.role = data.role;
  }
})
```

Comment: sir i tried above code but same result...userValue.subscribe not call after update value?

Comment: can you please create a minimal online example?